# How to add Context Menu into NavigationLink using SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm trying to add contextMenu into NavigationLink, using this code:

```
   NavigationLink(recent.name, destination: TextEditing(isNew: false, fileName: recent.name)).contextMenu{Button("Rename") {
                   // code
                    }
                   }
```

, but i receive swift compiler error: The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting your code to execute in a separate function in your view struct and then call it from the context menu:

```swift
// put this in your view struct
func action() {
    // code to run your menu action
}
```

And then call it from your context menu

```swift
NavigationLink(recent.name, destination: TextEditing(isNew: false, fileName: recent.name)).contextMenu {
                Button("Rename", action: action)
            }
```